# Python. Simple. i am making a encryption and decryption program. I cannot finalize part of my decryption process. It will not run. More info below

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to make an encryption and decryption program. I have the encryption function working perfectly (I will be adding more to it, but that is not my problem right now). For the decryption program, I have a place holder called 'originalText' which has no value by default. This variable will hold each decrypted character, and each character will be added one at a time. I have a for loop which calls a variable that is global which holds the encrypted letters. for every encrypted letter, it calls it, and attempts to convert it back to the original letter. Here is where I am stuck. Line 24 'temp = chr(c)' states that an integer is required, but got type string. I have tried surrounding both the 'c' and the 'chr' with the label int but neither have worked. i have tried adding the str to both, knowing that it would not work, and it did not. I am needing some help at this point. here is my code:

```
cipherText = ""

def encrypt(self):

    global cipherText

    for s in string:
    
        temp = ord(s)
        newChar = temp + 3
        newChar = chr(newChar)
        cipherText = cipherText + newChar

    print(cipherText)

def decrypt(self):

    originalText = ""

    for c in cipherText:

        temp = chr(c)
        newChar = temp - 3
        originalText = originalText + newChar

    print(originalText)


mark = 0
if ( decrypt(encrypt(string)) == string):
    print ("The test case passed!")
    mark = mark + 1
else:
    print ("ERROR: The test case failed!")

print("Your mark is", mark)
```

Comment: Similar to encryption, in decryption you first have to convert the character to its numeric value with "ord", do actual decryption and convert the result number back to character with "chr".

Comment: Ok, this is close to a Caesar's cipher. You should just be aware that adding 3 to the character code may end in non valid characters. But here the error message is an evidence that you must change `tmp = chr(c)` with `tmp = ord(c)`. I cannot post an answer because what you have shown if far from a [mre]...